# How do I retrieve value from async function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pretty new to this stuff, so probably doing this wrong, but it is my understanding to  get a number (in this case `startTypeValue`) rather than the promise of a number, I need a function something like this:

```
 render() {...
    var startTypeValue: number =0;

    const startType = async (accessToken: string): Promise<Number> => {

      const value = await startTypeGetPromise(accessToken) // how to unwrap the value inside this  promise
      startTypeValue= value.valueOf();
      console.log("inner"+JSON.stringify(startTypeValue, undefined, 2));
      return startTypeGetPromise(accessToken)
    }

   const startTypePromise = startType(this.props.accessToken);
   console.log("outer"+JSON.stringify(startTypeValue, undefined, 2));
```

`inner` gives 1 which is correct but `outer` gives 0. ( `startTypeGetPromise(accessToken)` does a DB call which returns 1). Is this because it is `async` and doesn't get the correct value in time? Or am I not setting the outer value correctly?

EDIT: following @ultrayam I added:

```
class myPage extends React.Component<MyPageProps> {
  constructor(props: MyPageProps| any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { startTypeValue: 0 };
  }
```

but I try:

```
this.state['startTypeValue']
```

and I get:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"startTypeValue"' can't be used to index type 'Readonly<{}>'.
```

Comment: render method isn't supposed to make async call yet as of v17 of react. You should use a lifecyle method to make the api call and store the data in state

Comment: Er...could you give an example, please?

Comment: I'd ignore the `.then()` answers and just make a `useEffect()` with an async function, so you can use `await` instead of `then` chaining (which is a little outdated).

Your component should render a `loading...` screen until the `useEffect()` has finished.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startType function is returning a Promise. To receive the resolved value of your async function you can use `then`.

For example,

```js
async function add(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}

let x = add(3, 6);
console.log(x); // Promise

add(3, 6).then(ret => console.log(ret)); // 9
```

In your **class** component,

```js
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
  }
  
  add = async (a,b) => {
    return a + b;
  }
  
  // set state
  componentDidMount() {
    this.add(1,2).then(ret => this.setState({value: ret}));
  }
  
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, so how do I extract the value of `ret` in your example?

Comment: You can create a state and this.setState in `then`. More on setState here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the above but still don't know how to get the value.

Comment: Use this.state.value in the render function

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me on CodeSandbox. You must use setState for update a value. Can you try this ? I hope it will helps you

```
    export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <MyClass />
    </div>
  );
}

async function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { startTypeValue: 0 };
  }

  loadResult = async () => {
    await add(3, 6).then((ret) => this.setState({startTypeValue: ret}));
  };

  // set state
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadResult();
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.startTypeValue}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function add (a,b) {
    const result = await a+b;
    return result
}

let test = add(5,10)
const[value, setValue] = useState(0); // using React State
test1.then(res => setState(res))
console.log(value) // will give you the result
```

Comment: Thanks but I get: `React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component`

Comment: Use State inside the class component then state = {
   value: 0
  }

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Why does javascript have to change its fundamental thesis for core operation every 8 to 16 months for the last decade?  Are they trying to obfuscate or is it an artifact of evolution?